# Is there a simple way to validate a hash of hash element comparsion?

Tags: perl, hash

Is there a simple way to validate a hash of hash element comparsion ?

I need to validate a Perl hash of hash element  $Table{$key1}{$key2}{K1}{Value} compare to all other elements in hash

third key will be k1 to kn  and i want comprare those elements and other keys are same

```
if ($Table{$key1}{$key2}{K1}{Value} eq $Table{$key1}{$key2}{K2}{Value}
    eq  $Table{$key1}{$key2}{K3}{Value} ) 
{
   #do whatever
}
```

Comment: What does "Kn key wille k1 to kn" mean?

Comment: third key will be differ and others are same and third element may be 1 to n...

Comment: Edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'all';

my @keys = map "K$_", 1..10;

print "All keys equal"
    if all { $Table{$key1}{$key2}{$keys[1]}{Value} eq $Table{$key1}{$key2}{$_}{Value} } @keys;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Data::Dumper` to help with a task like this, especially for a more general problem (where the third key is more arbitrary than 'K1'...'Kn'). Use `Data::Dumper` to stringify the data structures and then compare the strings.

```
use Data::Dumper;

# this line is needed to assure that hashes with the same keys output
# those keys in the same order.
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my $string1= Data::Dumper->Dump($Table{$key1}{$key2}{k1});

for ($n=2; exists($Table{$key1}{$key2}{"k$n"}; $n++) {

    my $string_n = Data::Dumper->Dump($Table{$key1}{$key2}{"k$n"});

    if ($string1 ne $string_n) {
        warn "key 'k$n' is different from 'k1'";
    }

}
```

This can be used for the more general case where `$Table{$key1}{$key2}{k7}{value}` itself contains a complex data structure. When a difference is detected, though, it doesn't give you much help figuring out where that difference is.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach to the problem is make utility function which will compare all keys if has same value returned from some function for all keys:

```
sub AllSame (&\%) {
  my ($c, $h) = @_;
  my @k = keys %$h;
  my $ref;
  $ref = $c->() for $h->{shift @k};
  $ref ne $c->() and return for @$h{@k};
  return 1
}

print "OK\n" if AllSame {$_->{Value}} %{$Table{$key1}{$key2}};
```

But if you start thinking in this way you can found this approach much more generic (**recommended way**):

```
sub AllSame (@) {
  my $ref = shift;
  $ref ne $_ and return for @_;
  return 1
}

print "OK\n" if AllSame map {$_->{Value}} values %{$Table{$key1}{$key2}};
```

If mapping operation is expensive you can make lazy counterpart of same:

```
sub AllSameMap (&@) {
  my $c = shift;
  my $ref;
  $ref = $c->() for shift;
  $ref ne $c->() and return for @_;
  return 1
}

print "OK\n" if AllSameMap {$_->{Value}} values %{$Table{$key1}{$key2}};
```

If you want only some subset of keys you can use hash slice syntax e.g.:

```
print "OK\n" if AllSame map {$_->{Value}} @{$Table{$key1}{$key2}}{map "K$_", 1..10};
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly complex structure. You should be looking into using [object oriented programming techniques](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltooc.html). That would greatly simplify your programming and the handling of these complex structures.

First of all, let's simplify a bit. When you say:

```
$Table{$key1}{$key2}{k1}{value}
```

Do you really mean:

```
my $value = $Table{$key1}->{$key2}->{k1};
```

or

```
my $actual_value = $Table{$key1}->{$key2}->{k1}->{Value};
```

I'm going to assume the first one. If I'm wrong, let me know, and I'll update my answer.

Let's simplify:

```
my %hash = %{$Table{$key1}->{$key2}};
```

Now, we're just dealing with a hash. There are two techniques you can use:

1. Sort the keys of this hash by value, then if two keys have the same value, they will be next to each other in the sorted list, making it easy to detect duplicates. The advantage is that all the duplicate keys would be printed together. The disadvantage is that this is a sort which takes time and resources.
2. Reverse the hash, so it's keyed by value and the value of that key is the key. If a *key* already exists, we know the other key has a duplicate value. This is faster than the first technique because no sorting is involved. However, duplicates will be detected, but not printed together.

Here's the first technique:

```
my %hash = %{$Table{$key1}->{$key2}};
my $previous_value;
my $previous_key;
foreach my $key (sort {$hash{$a} cmp $hash{$b}} keys %hash) {
    if (defined $previous_key and $previous_value eq $hash{$key}) {
        print "\$hash{$key} is a duplicate of \$hash{$previous_key}\n";
    }
    $previous_value = $hash{$key};
    $previous_key = $key;   
}
```

And the second:

```
my %hash = %{$Table{$key1}->{$key2}};
my %reverse_hash;
foreach $key (keys %hash) {
   my $value = $hash{$key};
   if (exists $reverse_hash{$value}) {
       print "\$hash{$reverse_hash{$value}} has the same value as \$hash{$key}\n";
   }
   else {
       $reverse_hash{$value} = $key;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to dereference `$Table{$key1}->{$key2}` to get the real hash, i.e. `my %hash = %{ $Table{$key1}->{$key2} };`. Otherwise you use the reference as a hash key (try enabling `warnings`)

Comment: OOP approach: no it would not simplify things. It would involve more code and more bugs. See mine functional approach and how simple and concise solution it brings. `my %hash = $Table{$key1}->{$key2};` doesn't work it should be `my %hash = %{$Table{$key1}->{$key2}};` or more efficient `my $hashref = $Table{$key1}->{$key2};`